# Как создать свою локализацию в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Делаю сайт на Yii2. Использую разные виджеты, например, GridView. Когда в конфиге делаю

```
'language' => 'ru'
```

все виджеты переключаются на русский язык, например, пишет `показано 10 из 100`.

Но мне нужно, что бы сайт был на украинском. Если прописать

```
'language' => 'ua'
```

не работает.

Есть ли возможность самому создать перевод для Yii2 и как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Украинский уже есть в Yii. Вы не правильно указали язык. Так:

```
'language' => 'uk'
```

Либо так:

```
'language' => 'uk_ua'
```

Полный список языков можно увидеть [здесь](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/tree/master/framework/i18n/data).

Да и вообще запомните, что украинский язык по ISO коду это `uk`, а не `ua`. Все iso коды [тут](https://www.andiamo.co.uk/resources/iso-language-codes/), либо на вики.

Answer (score 0):

Да, Yii2 позволяет создавать свои наборы с переводами. Для этого необходимо настроить конфигурацию определенным образом. Файлы переводов обычно располагают в `@app/messages/ua/app.php`

В конфиг в секцию `components` следует добавить такую настройку

```
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => \yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource::class,
                'basePath' => '@common/messages',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'ua',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                    'app/error' => 'error.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

[Более подробно по интернационализации Yii2](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/tutorial-i18n)